# Is this a correct way of proving that if $A^3-3A + I = 0$ then $A^{-1}=3I-A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A^3-3A+I = 0$, I multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$

$$(A^3-3A+I)*A^{-1} = 0$$

$$A^3*A^{-1} - 3A*A^{-1} + I*A^{-1} = 0$$

$$A^3*A^{-1} - 3I + A^{-1} = 0$$

$A(A^2*A^{-1})-3I+A^{-1} = 0$ Here I separated $A^3$ into $A$ and $A^2$ and multiplied the later by the inverse

$A(I)-3I+A^{-1} = 0$ and then I just add $3I$ to both sides and subtract $A$ from both sides getting this:

$$A^{-1}  = 3I - A$$

Comment: You cannot multiply the equation by $A^{-1}$ unless you've shown that $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should it be $A^{-1}=3I-A^2$?  Since $A^2\cdot A^{-1}=A$ but not $I$.

Since $A^3-3A+I=0$, we have $3A-A^3=I\Rightarrow (3I-A^2)A=I$. From the definition, we know $A^{-1}=3I-A^2$.

Comment: No, the book asks exactly for that question. Though maybe it could be a typo from the book though I really doubt it. Or they want me to give a counter proof. What really has me scratching my head here is what happens if I multiply a matrix elevated to N with its inverse and N > 2. I know if the matrix is elevated to the second power I can just separate it into A * A, multiply one of those A's by the inverse and get the identity to multiply it by A and get A. However I don't know what to do when N > 2.